# C# How to expose the constructor of a nested class only to the members of the parent class?

Tags: c#

Basically what I want to do is

```
class Parent{    
    public class Nested {
        private Nested(){
            //do something
        }
        /* ??? */ Nested CreateNested(){
            return new Nested ();   
        }
    }

    public Nested Foo(){
        Nested n = (???).CreateNested ();
        // do something about n
        return n;
    }
}
```

so that the users of the `Parent` class can see the `Nested` class, but are unable to create it (they can however get it from `Parent`). I know that for normal methods you can do it with explicit interface implementation, but it doesn't seem to work with constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply return an `INested`, which allows you to mark the nested class as `private`; thus the class is only accessible by `Parent`. You end up with something like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public interface INested
    {
    }
    private class Nested : INested
    {
        public Nested()
        {
        }
    }

    public INested Foo()
    {
        Nested n = new Nested();
        // do something about n
        return n;
    }
}
```